# When I press "." it writes "/"

Tags: shortcut

Somehow I do something that I don't want then when I press <kbd>.</kbd> it writes <kbd>/</kbd>. Because of this problem I cant scale my objects at the way I want.

Comment: Is your keyboard is set to a different language?

Comment: Yes it is Turkish "Q" but it doesn't happens all the time.

Comment: Hi. Please don't add 'solved' to the title. When you are able to accept the correct answer below, it will be marked as solved. Thanks.

Comment: Why can't I accept my answer in 2 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys I figured out the problem. In blender tab my keybords language turns to English. But only in the blender. But not at the start. I think when I do my models I press some keys then it turns to English. Thanks to @Pullup I solved my problem.

Comment: Left Alt + Shift toggles languages in Windows 10. https://www.isumsoft.com/windows-10/switch-between-inpute-language-on-windows-10.html

Comment: Mine is Windows 7 but it happens to me too. Thanks :)